# Laravel 5 default (authentication) app

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using the default laravel5 authentication app, and all menu links (in addition to the default home) work before I login. But once I login only the home link works and not any other. E.g.: When I click about it gives a '302 found' but it remains on the default home page and about does not show.

I am new to frameworks and OOP concepts, so please help and let me know if you require other code.

```
<?php

//routes.php


Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('about', 'AboutController@index');
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
Route::get('portfolio', 'PortfolioController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Comment: Please show us your `AboutController` code

Comment: Hi lukasgeiter. Thanx. here AboutController code: 
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AboutController extends Controller {
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
public function index()
    {
        return view('about');
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting HTTP 302 response which means redirect. I feel that there is some middleware in play which is protecting the routes incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working now. I am logged in and can view all the linked pages.
I commented out the following:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

Thanx